# Why my query 'REPLACE INTO...' does not work?

Tags: query, dbdelta

To insert or update data if data exists, I was using 'REPLACE INTO...' in a var `$query_string`
like this :

```
dbDelta( $query_string );
```

For some reason, the row is not insert. Why ?

Comment: `dbDelta` is extremely fussy over the query that it takes, down to the umber of spaces between sections of the query. Without seeing the full call with its value we can't answer this with 100% certainty, what is the full code that generates `$query_string`? What does the rest of the function look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is due to this code inside `dbDelta()` :

```
// Create a tablename index for an array ($cqueries) of queries.
foreach ( $queries as $qry ) {
    if ( preg_match( '|CREATE TABLE ([^ ]*)|', $qry, $matches ) ) {
        $cqueries[ trim( $matches[1], '`' ) ] = $qry;
        $for_update[ $matches[1] ]            = 'Created table ' . $matches[1];
    } elseif ( preg_match( '|CREATE DATABASE ([^ ]*)|', $qry, $matches ) ) {
        array_unshift( $cqueries, $qry );
    } elseif ( preg_match( '|INSERT INTO ([^ ]*)|', $qry, $matches ) ) {
        $iqueries[] = $qry;
    } elseif ( preg_match( '|UPDATE ([^ ]*)|', $qry, $matches ) ) {
        $iqueries[] = $qry;
    } else {
        // Unrecognized query type.
    }
}
```

ths function `dbDelta()` does not support 'REPLACE INTO' and that calls in the `else` with `// Unrecognized query type.` comment.